# Excel 'Forgot to Attach Attachment' alert VBA no longer working

Tags: vba, email, excel, outlook

I inserted the below VBA I found somewhere on the web into my **outlook** to catch e-mails which I have forgotten to attach the attachment to before they get sent.

It worked fine on initial application of the VBA however today I managed to forget to attach the attachment to an e-mail and sure enough it has stopped working for whatever reason. Can anybody help me rectify this please?

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim m As Variant

Dim strBody As String

Dim intIn As Long

Dim intAttachCount As Integer, intStandardAttachCount As Integer

On Error GoTo handleError

'Edit the following line if you have a signature on your email that includes images or other files. Make intStandardAttachCount equal the number of files in your signature.
intStandardAttachCount = 1

strBody = LCase(Item.Body)

intIn = InStr(1, strBody, "original message")

If intIn = 0 Then intIn = Len(strBody)

intIn = InStr(1, Left(strBody, intIn), "attach")

intAttachCount = Item.Attachments.Count

If intIn > 0 And intAttachCount <= intStandardAttachCount Then

   m = MsgBox("You forgot to attach your file didn't you?" & vbCrLf & "                   ...idiot" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "             Send it without?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbMsgBoxSetForeground)

    If m = vbNo Then Cancel = True

End If

handleError:

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Outlook Attachment Reminder Error: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Outlook Attachment Reminder Error"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Silently failing? Have you stepped through the code?

Comment: SHOOTING IN THE DARK: Change `intIn = InStr(1, strBody, "original message")` to `intIn = InStr(1, strBody, "original message", vbtextcompare)` Similarly for others. Also ensure that you follow your own advice `'Edit the following line if you have.....`

Comment: @SiddharthRout I have tried the code with different numbers in the 'intStandardAttachCount' section but it doesn't seem to make a difference and I am 99.99999999% sure my signature only counts one attachment. I will try switching out the code you mentioned and see if it makes a difference. thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `intin` and `intAttachCount` and `intStandardAttachCount` when you hit that block of code?

Answer (score 0):

> I inserted the below VBA I found somewhere on the web into my excel to catch e-mails which I have forgotten to attach the attachment to before they get sent.

Your code isn't going to work in Excel as is.

The event `Application_ItemSend` is an Outlook specific event handler. It is not present in Excel. It is tied to the Outlook action "Send." See [here](http://www.outlookforums.com/threads/92128-application_itemsend-not-accessed-when-sending-email-outside-outlook-i-e-word-or-send-to-mail-from/) for a description.

### Setup event handler for Excel to handle Outlook events

If you want to have this work for emails generated in *Excel* you are going to have to do something different.

In your situation, create a separate class module and name it `OutlookEventHandler` and paste the following:

```
Private WithEvents ol As Outlook.Application

Private Sub ol_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    'your code here

End Sub

Public Sub init()
    Set ol = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
End Sub
```

Then, in your `ThisWorkbook` module add the following:

```
Private olEH As OutlookEventHandler    
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Set olEH = New OutlookEventHandler
    olEH.init
End Sub
```

This will result in your event handler being called for emails sent by both Excel and Outlook.

Comment: Actually the question is quite confusing. On one hand OP says the code used to work and on the other hand OP started the question with `I inserted the below VBA I found somewhere on the web into my excel ....` Let's see what OP has to say about it

Comment: @SiddharthRout the only way this could have worked prior if it was in Outlook. The `Application_ItemSend` does not handle emails sent from Excel and is not present in Excel as a capturable event.

Comment: @SiddharthRout http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18504927#18504927

Comment: @enderland good morning guys, sorry for the late reply and thanks for attempting to answer. I meant to write that I inserted it into my outlook not my excel. I was not on the ball when I posted and have been out the office since.

Comment: @SiddharthRout good morning guys, sorry for the late reply and thanks for attempting to answer. I meant to write that I inserted it into my outlook not my excel. I was not on the ball when I posted and have been out the office since.